# spring mvc (HATEOS) - jackson json serialize error

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-hateoas

Its been 2 days I have been trying to resolve the json serialization issue in my project where I have bunch of entity classes mapped against each other with one-to-many relationships. So the error is

```
    org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.softcons.cas.entities.CASWeightageMaster.casQuestionMaster, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.softcons.cas.rest.CASQuestionMasterResource[&quot;casQuestionDescriptions&quot;]-&gt;org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]-&gt;com.softcons.cas.entities.CASQuestionDescription[&quot;casQuestionMaster&quot;]-&gt;com.softcons.cas.entities.CASQuestionMaster[&quot;casWeightageMaster&quot;]-&gt;com.softcons.cas.entities.CASWeightageMaster[&quot;casQuestionMaster&quot;]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.softcons.cas.entities.CASWeightageMaster.casQuestionMaster, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.softcons.cas.rest.CASQuestionMasterResource[&quot;casQuestionDescriptions&quot;]-&gt;org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]-&gt;com.softcons.cas.entities.CASQuestionDescription[&quot;casQuestionMaster&quot;]-&gt;com.softcons.cas.entities.CASQuestionMaster[&quot;casWeightageMaster&quot;]-&gt;com.softcons.cas.entities.CASWeightageMaster[&quot;casQuestionMaster&quot;])
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:244)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

There's one-to-many relationship between QuestionMaster & QuestionDescription also between QuestionMaster & Weightage master entities there's many-to-one relationship. I need to fetch a single record of QuestionMaster with its list of QuestionDescription records embedded. For this I made FetchType as eager between QuestionMaster & QuestionDescription, all used to work properly before I introduced this `List<QuestionDescription>` as a resource for json conversion. I keep getting the above error. Don't know where to modify since I tried everthing that I could find online.

question_master

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "cas_question_master")
    public class CASQuestionMaster extends BasicEntity {

    private String question;
    private boolean self;
    private boolean peer;
    private boolean supervisor;
    private boolean subordinate;
    private boolean deleteFlag;
    private boolean inactive;
    private Long deletedBy;
    private Date deletedOn;
    private CASWeightageMaster casWeightageMaster;
    private String questionDef;
    private List<CASQuestionDescription> casQuestionDescription;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = CASQuestionDescription.class, mappedBy = "casQuestionMaster", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    public List<CASQuestionDescription> getCasQuestionDescription() {
        return casQuestionDescription;
    }

    public void setCasQuestionDescription(
            List<CASQuestionDescription> casQuestionDescription) {
        this.casQuestionDescription = casQuestionDescription;
    }

    @Column(name = "question", length = 2000)
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "weightage_id_fk", nullable = false) 
    public CASWeightageMaster getCasWeightageMaster() {
        return casWeightageMaster;
    }

    public void setCasWeightageMaster(CASWeightageMaster casWeightageMaster) {
        this.casWeightageMaster = casWeightageMaster;
    }
    }
```

question_description

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cas_question_description")
public class CASQuestionDescription extends BasicEntity {

private CASQuestionMaster casQuestionMaster;
private String Description;
private boolean deleteFlag;
private Long deletedBy;
private Date deletedOn;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="question_id_fk", nullable=false)
public CASQuestionMaster getCasQuestionMaster() {
    return casQuestionMaster;
}
public void setCasQuestionMaster(CASQuestionMaster casQuestionMaster) {
    this.casQuestionMaster = casQuestionMaster;
}

@Column(name="description", nullable=false)
public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

}
```

weightage_master

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "cas_weightage_master")
    public class CASWeightageMaster extends BasicEntity {
    private int weightage;
    private List<CASQuestionMaster> casQuestionMaster;

    @Column(name = "weightage", nullable=false)
    public int getWeightage() {
        return weightage;
    }

    public void setWeightage(int weightage) {
        this.weightage = weightage;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = CASQuestionMaster.class, mappedBy = "casWeightageMaster", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<CASQuestionMaster> getCasQuestionMaster() {
        return casQuestionMaster;
    }

    public void setCasQuestionMaster(List<CASQuestionMaster> casQuestionMaster) {
        this.casQuestionMaster = casQuestionMaster;
    }

    }
```

controller code

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/findAll", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<CASQuestionMasterListResource> findAll()
    {
        try {
            CASQuestionMasterList casQuestionMasterList = new CASQuestionMasterList();            
            casQuestionMasterList.setCasQuestionMasterList(casQuestionMasterService.findAll());             
            CASQuestionMasterListResource res = new CASQuestionMasterListAsm().toResource(casQuestionMasterList);
            return new ResponseEntity<CASQuestionMasterListResource>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch(Exception exception)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(exception);
        }
    }
```

I have used Spring HATEOS for json format. Following is the resource file used to convert to json. Following are the resource files used for json conversion

QuestionMasterResource

```
public class CASQuestionMasterResource extends ResourceSupport {

private Long questionId;
private String question;
private Long casWeightageMasterId;

private List<CASQuestionDescription> casQuestionDescriptions;

public List<CASQuestionDescription> getCasQuestionDescriptions() {
    return casQuestionDescriptions;
}
public void setCasQuestionDescriptions(
        List<CASQuestionDescription> casQuestionDescriptions) {
    this.casQuestionDescriptions = casQuestionDescriptions;
}
public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}
public Long getQuestionId() {
    return questionId;
}
public void setQuestionId(Long questionId) {
    this.questionId = questionId;
}
public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public Long getCasWeightageMasterId() {
    return casWeightageMasterId;
}
public void setCasWeightageMasterId(Long casWeightageMaster) {
    this.casWeightageMasterId = casWeightageMaster;
}


public CASQuestionMaster toQuestionMaster(CASWeightageMaster casWeightageMaster){

    CASQuestionMaster casQuestionMaster = new CASQuestionMaster();

    casQuestionMaster.setId(this.questionId);
    casQuestionMaster.setCasWeightageMaster(casWeightageMaster);
    casQuestionMaster.setQuestion(this.question);

    return casQuestionMaster;
}

}
```

QuestionMasterListResource

```
    public class CASQuestionMasterListResource extends ResourceSupport {
    private List<CASQuestionMasterResource> casQuestionMasterResources = new ArrayList<CASQuestionMasterResource>();

    public List<CASQuestionMasterResource> getCasQuestionMasterResources() {
        return casQuestionMasterResources;
    }

    public void setCasQuestionMasterResources(
            List<CASQuestionMasterResource> casQuestionMasterResources) {
        this.casQuestionMasterResources = casQuestionMasterResources;
    }

    }
```

QuestionMasterList assembler

```
    public class CASQuestionMasterListAsm extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<CASQuestionMasterList, CASQuestionMasterListResource>{

    public CASQuestionMasterListAsm() {
        super(CASQuestionMasterController.class, CASQuestionMasterListResource.class);
    }   

    @Override
    public CASQuestionMasterListResource toResource(CASQuestionMasterList casQuestionMasterList) {
        List<CASQuestionMasterResource> casQuestionMasterResources = new CASQuestionMasterAsm().toResources(casQuestionMasterList.getCasQuestionMasterList());
        CASQuestionMasterListResource casQuestionMasterListResource = new CASQuestionMasterListResource();
        casQuestionMasterListResource.setCasQuestionMasterResources(casQuestionMasterResources);
        return casQuestionMasterListResource;       
    }
    }
```

Final note when logged to check if the records for question master entity is fetched eagerly it logs properly. Really not getting where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization to JSON can trigger the fetching of a collection, and since you don't have a hibernate session at that point you get the exception.

You can control this behaviour by using the [jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate), the docs explain how would you configure it

```
public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
        registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
    }
}
```

than register

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <!-- Use the HibernateAware mapper instead of the default -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="path.to.your.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

The module has a *Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING* settings, that tells whether the    object should be forced to be loaded and then serialized, which is by default set to *false*. This setup means that you won't get the exception but also that the list will not be included in the json response.

If you want to use the list in the response, you can either initialize it in your code at a place where you have a valid session like in the services, by calling e.g. `Hibernate.initialize(casQuestionMaster.getCasQuestionDescription())` or even better just calling any property of the list e.g. `getCasQuestionDescription().size()`, or set the `FORCE_LAZY_LOADING` to true, but this will attempt to load all the lazily loaded collections

Comment: thanks for ur reply Master Slave, with your timely answer I was able to resolve the above issue and to add to your answer unless we use `@JsonManagedReference` & `@JsonBackReference` for bidirectional mappings we may face stackoverflowerror...check this link...http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion...and thanks alot again..:)

Comment: glad you got your issue resolved, and a good comment, nice reference for future visitors facing the issue